# How to read PNG file using Imagemagick?

Tags: png, imagemagick

How to read PNG chunks that contain the image dimensions using Imagemagick? I am calling Imagemagick from my VC++ project. May I know the command for reading PNG chunks?

Comment: solved. I use Identify.exe from imagemagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. I use Identify.exe from imagemagick.